# "errmsg" : "exception: $unwind: value at end of field path must be an array"

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Query:

```js
db.trace.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$likes"},
    { $group : { _id : {"name" : "$name"}  } } 
]);
```

Mongo collection:

```js
"likes" : [
    {
        "category" : "test1",
        "name" : "test1",
        "created_time" : "2014-01-08T20:50:02+0000",
        "id" : "14157481053234234"
    },
    {
        "category" : "Publisher",
        "name" : "City Pulse",
        "created_time" : "2014-01-06T22:46:19+0000",
        "id" : "169217625001"
    }
]
```

Error:

```js
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: $unwind: value at end of field path must be an array",
    "code" : 15978,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Getting error that object is not array, but it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be in one or more documents `likes` is not array.

Check it: `db.trace.find( { $where : "!Array.isArray(this.likes)" } )`.